# Is it possible to call a lambda from another lambda?

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda

I'm trying to call a lambda from another lambda in this way:

```
fun fetch(
  onSuccess: (result: Any, onSet: () -> Unit) -> Unit
) {
  remoteConfigInstance.fetchAndActivate()
    .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
      if (task.isSuccessful) onSuccess(task.result, ()) // <- Here is the issue 
    }
}
```

I get an error trying to call the `onSet` lambda like this. Is there a correct approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is simply that `()` is not a lambda. Replace it with `{}`

Answer (score 1):

The answer pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71737869/4729721) is entirely correct, just as a potential way of improving your code, consider the following option:

```
fun fetch(
        onSuccess: (result: Any, onSet: (() -> Unit)? ) -> Unit) {
        remoteConfigInstance.fetchAndActivate()
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) onSuccess(task.result, null) // <- here you can now pass null, instead of an actual empty lambda
            }
    }
```

which allows you to instead make use of null if you don't want to do anything

Comment: thanks, I appreciate it, canvas is quite complicated and (good) tutorials are quite rare to find, so i'm essentially just trying out bits and pieces of different tutorials i find, doesn't help much that they are outdated @MikeM.